# MySQL match based on two fields, but have to prepend/append data to existing values

Tags: mysql

I'm having a difficult time crafting the appropriate query here.  I have two tables, lets call them `table1` and `table2`.  `Table1` has a field called QuantityAvailable that I would like to populate with the relavent data from `Table2` where the field is called Stock.  I'm trying to match values that have prepended static values in `table2`, and appended static values in `table1`.  Example:

Table1.CustomLabel
part#-append

Table2.InternalPartNumber
prependpart#

Ideally, what I am trying to do is take the static value from Table2 and Table1 and flip them so I have something that matches.  So essentially the values would look like:

prependpart#-append

in BOTH table1 and table2 so that I can then match values.  I was thinking `CONCAT` would help and this is what I pieced together, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
update table1, table2 set table1.QuantityAvailable = table2.Stock where table1.CustomLabel=concat("prepend",table1.CustomLabel) = table2.InternalPartNumber=concat(table2.InternalPartNumber,"append")
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it just that you need an AND rather than `=` between the WHERE clause's two conditions?

Comment: Wow I got a headache.  Remove the stuff outside the contcat and it should work.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `where concat("prepend", table1.CustomLabel) = concat(table2.InternalPartNumber, "-append")`

Comment: If the above solutions do not work, it would be nice to upload some sample data from your tables and what you expect to get when the query works.

Comment: Okay, let's try this; table1, CustomLabel has data such as 1234-part where as table2, InternalPartnumber field references the data as part1234.  Essentially, it is the "1234" part that I need to match up within both tables.  I was thinking using CONCAT to append "-part" to table2, InternalPartNumber field's data, and prepend "part" to Tabl1, CustomLabel fields values.  Or is there another way?